# Android and loading a listview from a sqlite database

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I'm creating an app which uses a Data Access Object class to load values into a Serializable object.

How do I do the following.

- Find the ListView object from the layout.
- Load the serialized list into the ListView

i'm reading the following doc http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

but i'm getting this error when i'm trying to follow that code but using the serialized list:

```
cannot find symbol
  [javac] symbol  : constructor ArrayAdapter(
```

i have this at the top of my file too

```
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
```

I'm trying to target 2.1 and above.

this is my code as it stands

http://pastie.org/1976415

Comment: please show us the code where you try to use the ArrayAdapter.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/992913

Comment: this is my first attempt at android, i've learned ios but this is different.

Comment: one error I found: you extend Activity, but you need to extend ListActivity. Does this solve the issue?

Comment: it now compiles right up to "setOnItemClickListener" so i've probably just missing and include somewhere for that too. i'm trying the app in the simulator with the error code commented out now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a ArrayAdapter when show data from a database in a ListView. Use a [CursorAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) (e.g. [SimpleCursorAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html)) instead. With a cursor and a CursorAdapter you will get much better performance as items get only read from the database when they are needed (e.g. the user scrolls the list).

When you use an ArrayAdapter you have do load all items in advance which is unnecessary as you might not need all of them. So using a Cursor and a CursorAdapter will give you better performance and reduce the memory usage.

Check [this blog post](https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/) for a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a list of `Ticket`s to the `<String>` adapter. Try to change it:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Ticket>(this, R.layout.main.list, tickets));
```

Comment: i'm having the compiler complain about 'tickets' now. "int cannot be dereferenced"